# C Program The game Totals can be played by any number of people

Tags: c

Write a program:
The game Totals can be played by any number of people. It starts with a total of 100 and each player in turn makes an integer adjustment between -20 to 20 to that total. The winner is the player whose adjustment makes the total equal to 5. 
The output should be:

```
Output
WE START WTITH 100. WHAT IS
YOUR ADJUSMENT? -20
         THE TOTAL IS: 80
YOUR ADJUSMENT? -35
         NOT AN INTEGER BEWTWEEN -20 AND 20
YOUR ADJUSMENT? 10
         THE TOTAL IS: 90
YOUR ADJUSMENT? 25
         NOT AN INTEGER BEWTWEEN -20 AND 20
YOUR ADJUSMENT? -20
         THE TOTAL IS: 70
YOUR ADJUSMENT? 7
         THE TOTAL IS: 77
YOUR ADJUSMENT? -15
         THE TOTAL IS: 62
YOUR ADJUSMENT? -20
         THE TOTAL IS: 42
YOUR ADJUSMENT? -19
         THE TOTAL IS: 23
YOUR ADJUSMENT? -18
         THE TOTAL IS: 5
THE GAME IS WON IN 10 STEPS
```

So here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int total=100, adjustment, counter=0;

    printf("WE START WITH 100. WHAT IS YOUR ADJUSMENT? ");
    scanf("%i", &adjustment);

    while (total != 5)
    {
        if (adjustment>=-20&&adjustment<=20)
        {
            total = total+adjustment;
            printf("The total is %i", &total);
            counter++;}
        else
        {
            printf("NOT AN INTEGER BEWTWEEN -20 AND 20");
            counter++;
        }

        printf("\nYOUR ADJUSMENT? ");
        scanf("%i", &adjustment);
    }

    printf("\nTHE GAME IS WON IN %d STEPS", &counter);
}
```

I don't know why every time I run the program, it gives me a very big number for the total. Please help me fix it!!!

Comment: try `scanf("%d", &adjustment);` and see how it goes.

Comment: When using %i to print an integer its same as %d..
But when used with scanf i -reads an optional signed decimal,octal,hex ...

Comment: No it does no help at all. @PK20

Comment: what is `a very big number for the total`? Please be more specific... Thanks.

Comment: You should check the return values of `scanf()` in order to make sure they successfully read sone value.

Comment: `printf("The total is %i", &total);` is printing the address of `total`, which is a very big number.  Use `printf("The total is %i", total);` instead.

Answer (score 4):

You have to write `printf("The total is %i", total);` instead of `printf("The total is %i", &total);` to print the value in `total`.

`printf("The total is %i", &total);` is undefined behavior because `%i` in `printf()` calls for `int` data, but `&total` is type `int*`.

Also, you have to write `printf("\nTHE GAME IS WON IN %d STEPS", counter);` instead of `printf("\nTHE GAME IS WON IN %d STEPS", &counter);` for the same reason.

Answer (score 0):

`&total` in the `printf("The total is %i", &total);` prints the address of total, that too in `signed format`, that is the reason you are getting very big number.

%i and %d is the format specifier for a signed integer,
%u for an unsigned integer.